# ASP.NET Response.Redirect() issue not working at false parameter

Tags: asp.net, redirect, expression, response, evaluate

Have trouble with the `Response.Redirect()` and getting the error:

***Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack***

I've googled and found some topics here, like:
[Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2041482/unable-to-evaluate-expression-because-the-code-is-optimized-or-a-native-frame-is)

Where people are offering to set the 2nd argument to the `false` value to make it work, like:

```
Response.Redirect("PageName.aspx", false);
```

But as for my program it isn't redirecting to the new one... It just continues to stay at this page.

I've done a breakpoint on other page, which to I want to redirect. But there wasn't any event for the breakpoint to catch. Looks like it just doesn't send the request to another page.

My code is rather big, so I've posted the code not here, but at ideone:
http://ideone.com/bQzCJd

The `Redirect()` method is on the `57th line`, which:

- occurs an exception, if the 2nd argument is set to `true`
- nothing happen, if is set to `false`

What must I do to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use `Response.Redirect("PageName.aspx")` but after the `try/catch`? Use a `bool` variable  e.g. `mustRedirect` which you can check before the redirect.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Because in future I want to make the redirection to the several pages. It may redirect to the Personal Cabinet, it may catch the notification, that such IP is banned from DB and I must to redirect to some forbidden area etc...

Comment: @OlegOrlov See this answer, and code http://stackoverflow.com/a/14641145/159270

Comment: @Aristos thanks for the interesting info about hacking issue, if is set to false value, but in my code exactly if I set to the `true` I'm getting such an exception. How could I fix it?

Comment: @OlegOrlov I have type the code that ignore this exception, and on the  link I explain some more about that.

Comment: @OlegOrlov: Even if you want to redirect to several pages you could use several `bools`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter pity... but it doesn't redirect even with the bools... Could you please look at my project, I've posted the VS-project here (requires vs2010 ): http://81.176.229.82/WebApplication1.zip

Answer (score 1):

> occurs an exception, if the 2nd argument is set to true

Yes, a `ThreadAbortException` because you [redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in a `Try-Catch`.

Why don't you use `Response.Redirect("PageName.aspx")` but after the `try/catch`? Use a `bool` variable  e.g. `redirectCabinet` which you can check before your redirect:

```
bool redirectCabinet = false;
try
{
    // ...
    if (tmpStr != String.Empty)
    {
        if (pageHandler.Request.HttpMethod == "GET")
        {
            if (pageHandler.Request.Params["method"] == "checkAuth")
            {
                // ...
                bool userExists = Convert.ToBoolean(mysqlObject.MakeScalar(ref mysqlConn,
                if (userExists)
                {
                   // ...
                    redirectCabinet = true;
                    //Response.Redirect("Cabinet.aspx");
                }
                // ...
            }
        }
        //....
    }
} catch (Exception exc)
{
    exc.ToString();
}

if(redirectCabinet)
    Response.Redirect("Cabinet.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to avoid the Abort Exception, and use the true to end the execution and move to the next page.

```
try
{
    // this is throw the ThreadAbortException exception
    Response.Redirect("SecondEndPage.aspx", true);
}
catch (ThreadAbortException)
{
    // ignore it because we know that come from the redirect
}
catch (Exception x)
{

}
```

Similar : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14641145/159270

Comment: thank you, but how will I redirect if there is a catch-block. I just will be caught in catch (ThreadAbortException) { } block and nothing will happen... But I need to fix the redirection process exactly.

Comment: @OlegOrlov Is not that, the redirect with true is send the redirect command and stop the execution. Try it. This code works :) you may need some return on the function, maybe there on the ThreadAbortException. Tim solution is similar, with a flag.

Comment: Event with Tim's solution it isn't redirecting, upper I've posted the variant of project with bools, you can look. http://81.176.229.82/WebApplication2.zip I've prepared the variant which you have suggested... but it also isn't redirecting and I don't understand 'why?', I don't want to use JavaScript for the redirection, because it would be bad for the application.

Comment: @OlegOrlov I see your code, are you sure that is called ? I do not see anything there to make it not redirect.

Comment: yes, I'm sure, because both methods ( Tim's and yours ) aren't redirecting to the needed page.

Comment: I'm using AJAX also in my page. Could it be a problem for the non-redirecting. Because I've tried also to call JS-function to redirect with the `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()` and no success... But JS piece of code can't be wrong, because it's just too simple. Don't know maybe to try Server.Transfer() will be the exit from this situation...

Comment: @OlegOrlov The redirect is not working is you call it from any ajax.

Comment: any AJAX ( as any JS-script ) isn't working also in that place as I said before. I've don't problem with erasing AJAX own scripts and using postbacks with <asp: /> tag. But I don't like this way... I want to know, why did I have problem here...

Answer (score 0):

Even with the solutions presented in the comments, it is not working as it should but if redirected with true `endRequest`, it should work.

Like this:

```
if(redirectCabinet)
    Response.Redirect("Cabinet.aspx",true);
```